# SQL - result fom weekday(time) and from week(without-Time)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to solve the problem. I need to get results from a working week (working hours are specified, for example, from 7:00 am to 8:00 pm), and I need to include weekends results (without specified time). But I dont know how to solve problem with weekday and include to result

```
select  
c.PatientId
,g.PatientId
,c.StartDate
,g.TransferOrdinalNumber

from ClinicalEvent C
join PatientIncomming G on C.PatientId=G.PatientId

where

(DATEPART(dw, StartDate) in (1,2,3,4,5))
and (
(CAST(StartDate as Time) between '20:00' and '23:59')
or 
(CAST(StartDate as Time) between '00:01' and '07:00')
)


and StartDate between '2020.02.01' and '2020.2.28'
and EventTypeId = '5365f53c-583b-4b53-bf50-2ec7c002e53c'
and g.TransferOrdinalNumber=1
group by C.PatientId, G.PatientId, c.StartDate, g.TransferOrdinalNumber
order by C.PatientId, G.PatientId
```

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? They are quite different, and I imagine you are only using one of them.

Comment: Why `GROUP BY` when no _set functions_ are involved? Do you simply want `SELECT DISTINCT`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `UNION ALL` statement can be helpful in the very basic method.

```
select  
c.PatientId
,g.PatientId
,c.StartDate
,g.TransferOrdinalNumber

from ClinicalEvent C
join PatientIncomming G on C.PatientId=G.PatientId

where

(DATEPART(dw, StartDate) in (1,2,3,4,5))
and (
(CAST(StartDate as Time) between '20:00' and '23:59')
or 
(CAST(StartDate as Time) between '00:01' and '07:00')
)


and StartDate between '2020.02.01' and '2020.2.28'
and EventTypeId = '5365f53c-583b-4b53-bf50-2ec7c002e53c'
and g.TransferOrdinalNumber=1
group by C.PatientId, G.PatientId, c.StartDate, g.TransferOrdinalNumber
UNION ALL

select  
c.PatientId
,g.PatientId
,c.StartDate
,g.TransferOrdinalNumber

from ClinicalEvent C
join PatientIncomming G on C.PatientId=G.PatientId

where

(DATEPART(dw, StartDate) in (6,7))
--and (
--(CAST(StartDate as Time) between '20:00' and '23:59')
--or 
--(CAST(StartDate as Time) between '00:01' and '07:00')
--)


and StartDate between '2020.02.01' and '2020.2.28'
and EventTypeId = '5365f53c-583b-4b53-bf50-2ec7c002e53c'
and g.TransferOrdinalNumber=1
group by C.PatientId, G.PatientId, c.StartDate, g.TransferOrdinalNumber
    order by C.PatientId, G.PatientId
```